# Data shifting in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a number of 32 bit. I need only its first 8 bits. I think I can do this by two methods: one is by shifting the number to 24 bits right and other is by simply assigning the last 8 bits to a variable.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
module Data_shiftin(
input reset_n, clk,
input [31:0]    data_in,
output [31:0] data_out
);  
  reg [31:0] data_reg;
  reg data_out;
  always @ (posedge clk)
  begin 
      data_out<=data_in[31:23];
  end
endmodule
```

But I am getting only last bit i.e. 32nd bit of the number. I don't know where  I am doing error. 
Thanks!

P.S: I am a newbie to this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment you have is correct, but you are only getting one bit because you are redeclaring `data_out` as a single-bit reg.  Try changing:

```
reg data_out
```

To:

```
reg[31:0] data_out
```

A better option though it to use Verilog-2000 style port declarations and place the `reg` keyword in the port list.

Example:

```
module Data_shiftin(
  input  wire        reset_n, 
  input  wire        clk,
  input  wire [31:0] data_in,
  output reg  [31:0] data_out
); 

always @ (posedge clk)
  begin 
    data_out <= data_in[31:23];
  end
endmodule
```

Note also that your tool may warn you about a width mismatch because you are assigning an 8-bit value to a 32-bit value.  To explicitly assign only the lower 8 bits of `data_out` you should use:

```
data_out[7:0] <= data_in[31:23]
```